# AX 2009 Net Requirements - Requirement Date in the past

Tags: axapta

in my Net Requirements screen for a particular item in AX 2009, there is a Production line requirement generated by Master Planning that has a Requirement Date in the past (11/4/2021 - 18 months ago).

The Production Order attached to it only exists in the Net Requirements, not in the list of production orders. Right-click > Go to Main Table only brings up an empty screen.

If I go into the ReqTrans table and delete that requirement, then running Master Planning will recreate the requirement with the same Production line number.

The Pegging reference is for On-hand, with a settled quantity for the same amount as the quantity on the requirement.

Could anyone explain what this is telling me, and how to remove it if possible?

Thanks so much!

[image: Net Requirements with Pegging]

Comment: It sounds like your production order doesn't exist and you have some orphaned records? This isn't really programming related though.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought I could still ask the question here. It does seem like an orphan record. I wrote a job to delete it but it is recreated identically after Master Scheduling is rerun. There must be something that is causing it to be recreated, but I'm not sure what, or where to look.

Comment: This seems like a very environment specific thing and `AX2009` is so old that it's difficult to jump into a similar environment to even guess at what could be happening in code and/or if there are customizations. Your best bet is probably to debug it or look on LCS for hotfixes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for inventory transactions (`InventTrans` records) for the item at the specific date.

If the production order is deleted or ended, you will have to delete the `InventTrans` record using code. Delete using the `delete` method, not the `doDelete` metod.

Comment: Thanks Jan! I often see comments on the Internet saying that InventTrans should never be modified.  I just wanted to check with you, have you deleted records from InventTrans in the past without issue? Thanks again!

Comment: It is often necessary to delete `InventTrans` records to resolve data inconsistencies. Sometimes also zeroing `remain` fields on `SalesLine` or `ProdBOM` lines.

Comment: I deleted the record from inventTrans and it removed the requirement after Master Scheduling was rerun for the item. Thanks for all your help Jan!